# Showing total on stacked bar Plotly

Tags: python, visualization, plotly

How do you show the total on a stacked bar graph in Plotly.

I can hover and see the individual values for each group but not the total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the sum in the `text` attribute and show in the `hoverinfo`.

[image]

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
zoo_sf = [20, 14, 23]
zoo_la = [12, 18, 29]

trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(
    x=animals,
    y=zoo_sf,
    name='SF Zoo',
    hoverinfo='text',
    text=[('Total: ' + str(x + y) + '<br>SF: ' + str(y)) for x, y in zip(zoo_la, zoo_sf)] 
)

trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(
    x=animals,
    y=zoo_la,
    name='LA Zoo',
    hoverinfo='text',
    text=[('Total: ' + str(x + y) + '<br>LA: ' + str(x)) for x, y in zip(zoo_la, zoo_sf)]
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(barmode='stack')
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically show the total? ie. when you hide the `LA Zoo`, then total becomes the same as `SF Zoo`

Comment: Not that I know of. You could do it directly in Javascript but not via Python and Plotly

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I add totals to plotly stacked bar charts:

```
x_labels = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
totals = [32, 32, 52]

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=x_labels,
    y=[20, 14, 23],
    text=[20, 14, 23],
    name='SF Zoo'
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=x_labels,
    y=[12, 18, 29],
    text=[12, 18, 29],
    name='LA Zoo'
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

total_labels = [{"x": x, "y": total*1.05, "text": str(total), "showarrow": False} for x, total in zip(x_labels, totals)]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig = fig.update_layout(annotations=total_labels)

fig.show()
```

[plotly bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B93Gt.png)

Comment: Using wmp3's solution gave me this error:
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'annotations' property of layout
        Invalid elements include: [[{'x':
It seems that annotations doesn't like the double [[. To resolve this I placed the content of total_labels directly in the update_layout eg fig=fig.update_layout(annotations=[{"x": x etc. And that seems to work.

Comment: It may be explained that I didn't use zip but a dataframe.