# How to add a title above the whole stacked bars using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I'm using Plotly to create some graphics and render them in a Flask app using plotly.js.
`
[image]

I'd like to put the total value (the sum of the stacked bar values) of each bar at the top of the bar.

I'm using as entry data a Dataframe and I calculated the top values using groupby:

```
fig = px.bar(data, x="Ano", y="Área (km²)", barmode='stack', color='Classe')
gp = data.groupby(['Ano']).sum()
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- this is really repackaging of this answer [Showing total on stacked bar Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450028/showing-total-on-stacked-bar-plotly)
- adapted to use a dataframe and Plotly Express

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Ano": np.random.choice(list(range(2019, 2022)), 10),
        "Área (km²)": np.random.randint(10, 25, 10),
        "Classe": np.random.choice(["DS", "DG", "CS"], 10),
    }
)

fig = px.bar(df, x="Ano", y="Área (km²)", color="Classe")

fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        {"x": x, "y": total * 1.05, "text": str(total), "showarrow": False}
        for x, total in df.groupby("Ano", as_index=False).agg({"Área (km²)": "sum"}).values
    ]
)
```

[image]

#### year number as a categorical

- this solution works where x-axis is a categorical
- clearly this is done by bashing sample data.  (year is better represented as a integer than a string)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Ano": np.random.choice(list(range(2019, 2022)), 10),
        "Área (km²)": np.random.randint(10, 25, 10),
        "Classe": np.random.choice(["DS", "DG", "CS"], 10),
    }
)

# force it to be categorical !!!! no sample data :-(
df["Ano"] = df["Ano"].astype(str)
# ordered array of categories, so can be used across traces and annotations
anoa = df["Ano"].sort_values().unique()
fig = px.bar(df, x="Ano", y="Área (km²)", color="Classe", category_orders={"Ano":anoa})

# values for annotation
dft = df.groupby("Ano", as_index=False).agg({"Área (km²)": "sum"})
# place annotation based on it's position in categories array
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        {"x": (anoa == x).argmax(), "y": total + (dft["Área (km²)"].max()/15), "text": f"{total} km²", "showarrow": False}
        for x, total in dft.values
    ]
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Rob, you're right, I should find this answer, and tks for your answer.

Comment: I follow your recommendations but initially I got the following result:

Comment: it's not possible to paste an image into a comment.  you can update your question with what you have attempted and the outcome

Comment: I recommend deleting your answer that is not an answer but supplementary update to question.   best practice for SO is to provide your sample data rather than expect people to synthesize it for you to provide an answer

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll do that.

Comment: @MauroAssis did second solution using categorical work for you?