# How to show total of entire plotly stacked bar?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly bar chart as below:

[image]

Is it possible to get the total for each bar and not the totals of each section of the stacked bars? I'd like to show the total for each stacked bar above each bar.

The code I have to produce the bar chart:

````
        bar_chart_3 = px.bar(
        df_scheme,
        x='Scheme',
        y='Total',
        hover_name='Calc Type',
        text='Total',
        color='Scheme',
        title='Number of scheme categories'
    )
    bar_chart_3.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'})
    bar_chart_3.update_layout(
        width=500,
        showlegend=False,
    ) ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing total on stacked bar Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450028/showing-total-on-stacked-bar-plotly)

Answer (score 2):

There may be another way to do this, but you can use the text mode of scatter plots on a stacked bar chart drawn in express to display the totals using the values of the data frames that you have summed.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.medals_long()
df_sum = df.groupby('medal').sum()

fig = px.bar(df,
             x="medal",
             y="count",
             color="medal",
             text_auto=True           
            )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='text',
                         x=df_sum.index,
                         y=df_sum['count'].tolist(),
                         text=[str(x) for x in df_sum['count'].tolist()],
                         textposition='top center',
                         showlegend=False
                        ))
fig.show()
```

[image]